# How to group rows in sql with particular order in bunch of sets

Tags: sql, teradata

Lets say I have a table with 3 columns

| one | two | three |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | LF | 1 |
| x | FI | 2 |
| x | LF | 3 |
| x | FI | 4 |
| x | FI | 5 |
| x | FI | 6 |
| x | LF | 7 |
| x | FI | 8 |
| x | LF | 9 |
| x | FI | 10 |
| x | LF | 11 |
| x | LF | 12 |
| x | LF | 13 |
| x | LF | 14 |
| x | FI | 15 |

Now what I want is to group the 'two' column and take the lowest 'third' column value which will give me output like

| one | two | three |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | LF | 1 |
| x | FI | 2 |
| x | LF | 3 |
| x | FI | 4 |
| x | LF | 7 |
| x | FI | 8 |
| x | LF | 9 |
| x | FI | 10 |
| x | LF | 11 |
| x | FI | 15 |

How Can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: sql server but MySQL will also work

Comment: Also, are  you using the completely unsupported SQL Server 2008, or the only 1 year left of extended support SQL Server 2012? You've tagged both.

Comment: Actually i am using teradata SQL

Comment: Then you can add the <teradata> tag, and remove the sql server tags...

Comment: But it supports sql server functions also right? sorry If I am sounding dumb i am new to this

Comment: *"Actually i am using teradata SQL"* then *why* did you tag MySQL, SQL Server, SQL Server 2008 **and** SQL Server 2012..?

Comment: Some functions/functionality are supported by almost any dbms, while others are not. That's why the correct dbms tag is important!

Comment: ok added teradata

Comment: *"ok added teradata"* You should have removed the erroneous tags at the same time; I have done this for you. Tagging correctly is important, and tagging conflicting tags is *very* confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want the rows where there is a change.  You can use `lag()`:

```
select one, two, three
from (select t.*,
             lag(two) over (order by three) as prev_two
      from t
     ) t
where prev_two is null or prev_two <> two;
```

Comment: Note that *if* the OP is using the (completely unsupported) SQL server 2008 (which they have tagged along side SQL Server 2012) this won't work, as `LAG` was introduced in SQL Server 2012.